python overlaying information on base class
I have a base class ASTNode and a bunch of subclasses. I cannot/want not modify these classes.
The ASTNodes represent a tree.
Now I'd like to add type checking to my AST (meaning I need to add new data to every node.)
A) I create a new Typed-variant for every ASTNode subclass and create a new tree with these new classes. I'd like to avoid this since I would have to manually create a new class/change it every time I update the original AST.
B) I create a new class TypedASTNode that has a reference to the original ASTNode and also stores the additional typing information. Although now when I want to traverse the tree I have to do this via the stored ASTNodes and I cannot go from ASTNode back to TypedASTNode to retrieve the typing information. This means I would have to store another copy of the tree inside the TypedASTNodes. I really dislike this idea, since it opens up the possibility of inconsistencies between both trees later on.
        
class ASTNode:
    @property
    def children(self): return ...
    
    ...

class ASTLiteral(ASTNode):
    ...

class ASTExpr(ASTNode):
    ...
    
class TypedASTNode:
    def __init__(self, node: ASTNode):
        self._node = node
    
    @property
    def type(self): return ...
    @property
    def node(self): return self._node 
    
    

Ideally I would like to be able to overlay the information on the original ASTNodes somehow. Is there a pythonic way to solve this problem neatly or do I have to go with the duplicated tree approach?
Note: Working typehints are a must.

You could have a dict going from ASTNode to TypedASTNode, to allow you to access this additional information, without any modification to the original classes.

@jasonharper this would be a cleaner solution, although it would also introduce additional runtime complexity that could be avoided the with uglier solution.
